# Change small cube to a High cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my little cube to change to a bigger one when i click the upper arrow, and change back when i pres the down arrow. I have tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSkift : MonoBehaviour {

    public gameObject myObject1;

    public gameObject myObject2;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            myObject1.SetActive (false);
            myObject2.SetActive (true);

        }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        myObject2.SetActive(false);
        myObject1.SetActive(true);

    }

    }
}
```

When i try to run it it says:

```
Assets/PlayerSkift.cs(9,9): error CS0118: `UnityEngine.Component.gameObject' is a `property' but a `type' was expected
```

I have no idea what that means, so if you know it, or know how to do it in a other way. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public gameObject myObject1;

public gameObject myObject2;
```

the above code, as per [this discussion](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1379319/unityenginecomponentgameobject-is-a-property-but-a.html), appears to have a typo.

`gameObject` should be `GameObject`.

Comment: Thanks man. It works now:)